# Problematic mysql query how to filter by multiple ID's

Tags: mysql

Full code I use:

```
 $query18 = 'SELECT group_concat(id) as qc10 FROM tblorders WHERE date LIKE \'' . date ('Y-m-') . '%\'';
    $result18 = mysql_query($query18);
    $data18 = mysql_fetch_array($result18);
    $qc10 = $data18['qc10'];
  $query19 = "SELECT count(id) as qc11 FROM bl_orderitems WHERE orderid=$qc10";
    $result19 = mysql_query($query19);
    $data19 = mysql_fetch_array($result19);
```

$query19 looks like this:

```
'SELECT count(id) FROM bl_orderitems WHERE orderid=7,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14';
```

But it doesn't work. How can I list those ID's so it would actually work?

THANKS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `WHERE orderid IN(7,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)`

so the query would be:

```
'SELECT count(id) FROM bl_orderitems WHERE orderid IN(7,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using IN

SELECT count(id) FROM bl_orderitems WHERE orderid IN (7,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to match a value for orderid that is one of those options that you listed,  this should work:

```
SELECT count(orderid) FROM bl_orderitems WHERE orderid IN (7,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);
```